# MVC 4 ListBox populated with another ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, listbox

I need an approach on how to populate a ListBox in a view depending of the selected value in another ListBox in the same view.

for example i would need a ListBox of Cities populated with the name of the Country selected in another ListBox.

thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: [mvc cascading dropdownlist](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mvc+cascading+dropdownlist&oq=mvc+cascad&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i60l2j69i59j0.4092j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the home controller I have decided to use the collection initializer to build the list of countries but more importantly I felt the code was cleaner by using the ViewBag dynamic over ViewData.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var countries = new List<string> {"USA", "UK", "India"};
        var countryOptions = new SelectList(countries);
        ViewBag.Countries = countryOptions;
        return View();
    }
```

Next is the GetStates() action method. Here I have made one change that enables me to retrieve the states over a HttpGet request. The reason for this is I believe that HttpGet is the best fit for this request as we are simply retrieving information form the server. If we were adding or updating states then a HttpPost request would be required.

```
  public JsonResult GetStates(string country)
    {
        var states = new List<string>();
        switch (country)
        {
            case "USA":
                states.Add("California");
                states.Add("Florida");
                states.Add("Ohio");
                break;
            case "UK":
                states.Add("London");
                states.Add("Essex");
                break;
            case "India":
                states.Add("Goa");
                states.Add("Punjab");
                break;
        }

        //Add JsonRequest behavior to allow retrieving states over http get
        return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The second, and final, part of my solution is the Index.cshtml file. In this file I have the html for the form as well as the javascript required to retrieve the states from the server.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>Select country:</div>
    <div>@Html.DropDownList("country", 
                            ViewBag.Countries as SelectList, 
                            "Please select", 
                            new { id = "country" })
    </div>
    <div>Select state:</div>
    <div>
        <select id="state" disabled="disabled"></select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}


@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#country').on('change', function() {
                var stateDropdown = $('#state');
                //disable state drop down
                stateDropdown.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                //clear drop down of old states
                stateDropdown.empty();

                //retrieve selected country
                var country = $(this).val();
                if (country.length > 0) {
                    // retrieve data using a Url.Action() to construct url
                    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetStates")', {
                        country: country
                    })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        //re-enable state drop down
                        stateDropdown.removeProp('disabled');
                        //for each returned state
                        $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                            //Create new option
                            var option = $('>option /<').html(state);
                            //append state states drop down
                            stateDropdown.append(option);
                        });
                    })
                    .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                        console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have installed Json package but i can't see it in references... i am referencing it directly using browser, but then the JsonResult type doesn't appear...

Comment: I have been able to use JSonResult, but the return Json(...) is in grey.. it says "the name Json doesn't existes in the current context".

Comment: JSon now it's in context, i foogot to add the @using System.Web.Helpers but now the problem is that it says that Json is a type and it's being used like a variable

Comment: Finalyy i solved the problem, i was using the code in a class not derived from controller.

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it helps you or else please post the answer